# downloading a csv file

Tags: php, csv

im having a problem when downloading a csv file using php, ideally i want to visit a page and it just prom,pts me to save the file-

i have tried this here-

```
$filename = 'dump.csv';
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
```

and it has been returning a empty file, even though when i do-

echo filesize($filename);

it returns 19000 ?

Comment: what about trying to understand what you are or what you are not doing. read up on functions and learn the basics of a language. dont copy some codes from some places and expect it to do what you want to do but rather try to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the content of the file in and then output it.

Otherwise you are just sending the headers telling the browser to expect the file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to echo out the contents of the file.  For example, after your header functions you would have something like:

```
$fh = fopen($filename, "r");
while($line = fgets($fh)){
 echo $line;
}
fclose($fh);
```